# Icon for UITableViewRowAction is shown on iOS 13, but not on iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uitableviewrowaction

Ok, I've encountered a strange behaviour (bug) by `UITableViewRowAction`. I'm trying to add an icon to a swipe left action. 
Bellow is my code for setting an icon inside the table view delegate's `tableView(_:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)` method (action is an instance of `UIContextualAction`):

```
action.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: Constants.swipeActionImageSize)
        .image(actions: { _ in
            Constants.messageReplyIcon.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero,
                                                       size: Constants.swipeActionImageSize))
    })
```

I'm using this solution since need to resize the image a little bit. This works fine on iOS 13 but on iOS 12 (actually, running on iOS 12.2), it renders the image as a white circle. Bellow, you can see screenshots of the icon on iOS 13 simulator and on iOS 12.2 simulator one after another.

**iOS 13**

[image]

**iOS 12.2**

[image]

Note that this happens even when I simply set the image, without doing all that fancy stuff for resizing.

However, when I look at the image in UI Debugger while sill on iOS 12, I see the following:

[image]

I suspect, the `UIContextualAction` applies some tint color to the icon on iOS 12, but can't figure out why, and because of that, can't find a solution.

Maybe, you've encountered something like this, or have ideas about the reasons? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any solution you found ?

Answer (score 0):

`UIContextualAction` on older versions of iOS converts the image to a template that will be painted white. Although the documentation doesn't say anything about it.

See about templates:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/providing_images_for_different_appearances
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/renderingmode